# Parse.com - JSON Import Date Field Error

Tags: ios, json, date, parse-platform

I am trying to import some JSON data into one of my tables in Parse.com.  When doing so, I get the following error:

**Import encountered the following error: error 111: invalid type for key startDate, expected date, but got string**

The data is below:

```
[
  {
    "title":"Software Webinar",
    "location":"Kingsview Financial",
    "host":"Josh Chase",
    "startDate":"10/13/2014 12:30",
    "EndDate":"10/13/2014 13:30",
    "eventType":"TA",
    "eventDescrioption":"Informative webinars on utilize and maximize all the features of the TA Trader platform."
  }
]
```

I've tinkered with the date format a bit but to no avail. Just trying to import some data, and have to use JSON data to do so.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format)

Comment: Thanks @borrrden, I have checked out that post before. Very informative, a good education for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formate your date like this:

```
"startDate": {

    "__type": "Date",
    "iso": "2014-10-13T12:30:00.000Z"
}
```

You JSON will look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "title":"Software Webinar",
    "location":"Kingsview Financial",
    "host":"Josh Chase",
    "startDate": {

        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "2014-10-13T12:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "EndDate": {

        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "2014-10-13T13:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "eventType":"TA",
    "eventDescrioption":"Informative webinars on utilize and maximize all the features of the TA Trader platform."
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks @Rashad.  I think this worked.  Now I'm running into a different error, having to do with "file not containing data or is improperly formatted".  I assume this means that I am passed the date issue. Update: fixed that, just needed to wrap my JSON in a { "results": [] } item.

Comment: @nlabhart> Nice to hear that... :)